# What's the standard way to define an Objective-C library version number?

Tags: objective-c, class, version, nsobject

I'm creating an Objective-C library to be distributed with various apps, and I'd like consumers of the library to be able to check the version. I see that there is a `+version` method on NSObject, but it’s just an integer; I think an NSNumber or even [semantic version](http://semver.org/) would be more useful. My initial thought is just to define a `+VERSION` method on my library's main class and have it return an NSNumber. But I thought maybe there is some standard-ish way to define library or class versions in Objective-C. Is there?

Comment: If this is a framework, you can specify a version in the bundle's plist.  If this is a static library, you can add a char array constant of a certain length and format.  Or the old `#define vMajor/vMinor/vPatch n`

Comment: What is “the old `#define vMajor/vMinor/vPatch`? My Google-foo fails me…

Comment: Something like `#define kMajorVersion 1` `#define kMinorVersion 0` `#define kPatchVersion 27` (for 1.0.27).  Obviously, these constants would be namespaced appropriately and stuck somewhere public.

Comment: Ah, okay, so nothing formal, really. Thanks.